# print периодически перестает работать. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решил написать простую "камень, ножницы, бумага". Когда проверял, у меня появилась проблема, что когда в строке `user_thing = input("выберите предмет(камень, ножницы, бумага):\n")` пишу камень, то есть 2 варианта: код запускается нормально; часть кода просто пропускается. Что делать?

```
import random

bot_thing = random.randint(1, 3)
user_thing = input("выберите предмет(камень, ножницы, бумага):\n")

if bot_thing == 1:
    bot_thing = "камень"
elif bot_thing == 2:
    bot_thing = "ножницы"
elif bot_thing == 3:
    bot_thing = "бумага"

if user_thing == "ножницы" and bot_thing == "камень":
    print("Вы проиграли!\nПротивник выбрал камень")
elif user_thing == "ножницы" and bot_thing == "бумага":
    print("Вы победили!\nПротивник выбрал бумагу")

elif user_thing == "камень" and bot_thing == "ножницы":
    print("Вы победили!\nПротивник выбрал ножницы")
elif user_thing == "камень" and bot_thing == "ножницы":
    print("Вы проиграли!\nПротивник выбрал ножницы")

elif user_thing == "бумага" and bot_thing == "камень":
    print("Вы победили!\nПротивник выбрал камень")
elif user_thing == "бумага" and bot_thing == "ножницы":
    print("Вы проиграли!\nПротивник выбрал ножницы")

elif user_thing == bot_thing:
    print("Ничья!\nПротивник выбрал ", bot_thing)

input()
```

Ошибка происходит в части кода:

```
elif user_thing == "камень" and bot_thing == "ножницы":
    print("Вы проиграли!\nПротивник выбрал ножницы")
elif user_thing == "камень" and bot_thing == "ножницы":
    print("Вы победили!\nПротивник выбрал ножницы")
```

Comment: Как именно часть кода пропускается по-вашему?

Comment: Почему вы вообще решили, что там часть кода пропускается и какая-то ошибка? Даже то, что вы исправили одно условие не навело ни на какие мысли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь:

```
elif user_thing == "камень" and bot_thing == "ножницы":
    print("Вы проиграли!\nПротивник выбрал ножницы")
elif user_thing == "камень" and bot_thing == "ножницы":
    print("Вы победили!\nПротивник выбрал ножницы")
```

у вас два раза одно и то же условие - камень против ножниц. А варианта "камень против бумаги" у вас вообще нет.